# Uninstall old version of Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient from GAC

Tags: .net, assemblies, gac, ssas, .net-assembly

I need to uninstall an old version of this DLL from the GAC in order to run an installer, but I receive an "Access Denied" error. Does anybody have an idea on how I can remove this DLL?

Comment: Probably because you're not supposed to uninstall things from the GAC yourself manually. And secondarily, probably because you don't have administrative privileges.

Comment: i'm using an admin account and have to uninstall it because the old version is blocking a setup-program. the newer version of the .dll is already in the gac

Comment: How can the old version be blocking a setup program? And why can't the setup program remove it automatically? Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: the setup is looking for a certain version. if it finds an older version the setup cancels.

Comment: Vendor (MS) recommendation is "uninstall old version from the GAC

Answer (score 1):

The command you're looking for is:

```
gacutil.exe /u <assemblyname>
```

The documentation for `gacutil.exe` is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c.aspx). You obviously will need the SDK for this, `gacutil.exe` is no longer installed with the .NET Framework.

Also, make sure that you're running the *correct version* of `gacutil.exe`. It should match the version of the assembly that you're trying to uninstall.

Finally, make sure that you're running with administrative privileges. You may need to start an elevated command prompt to execute the command.

Comment: Unable to uninstall: assembly is required by one or more applications
Pending references:
              SCHEME: <WINDOWS_INSTALLER>  ID: <MSI>  DESCRIPTION : <Windows Installer>

Comment: how can i remove this pending reference?

Comment: @stefan: Check the registry entries at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Assemblies\Global` and `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Assemblies\Global`. If they contain any references to the assembly, remove them. For more information, see [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alanshi/archive/2003/12/10/42690.aspx).

Comment: @cody thx for the help. now i could uninstall the assemblies but the setup still doesn't work :( ...

Comment: @stefan: Do you get an error message? I'm not sure why it doesn't work.